# Matrix problem by double slash

Tags: matrix

EE 2.4.0
Matrix 2.2.4

I've got a big problem with expression and a matrix field.
Matrix field:
- celtype: text
- formating: none
- content: all

The field is for a facebook address. And one way or an other my client puts a double slash in the address. The result is that the entry, if you want to change that, gives:
*Fatal error: Call to a member function row_array() on a non-object in /home/sites/site38382/web/system/expressionengine/libraries/File_field.php on line 314*

I can't delete the entry the checkbox is grey. I found out what went wrong by cloning the entry and saw the double slash. But when I clone the entry I get twice the entry. The only way to get rid of this entry is in the database.

How can I delete the entry / how can I precvent this in the future / is this a matrix error?

greetings,

Franka